# merge two regular expressions in vs2010

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to search keywords in vs2010 with regular expressions and wanted to merge two expressions into one

Expression1: write a regular expression to get all matches starts with "global.ready_one"

My solution : `{<global.ready_one}`

Expression2: write a regular expression to get the all matches which contains ".get"

My solution : `{[get]}`

now i wanted to merge these two expressions and resultant expression should return the lines starts with "global.ready_one" and contains ".get"

Please suggest a solution

**Edit:**

**Example:**  it should return all of the below results

```
 "global.ready_one_Manual_getSignal"
"global.ready_one_Auto_getSignal"
"global.ready_two_Manual_getSignal_Evaluation"
```

Comment: Do you want lines that A) match *either* Expression1 **or** Expression2?  Or do you want B) lines that match *both* Expression1 **and** Expression2?

Comment: Also, VS2010 is not a language; it is an IDE. What language and framework are you using?!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart guess he wants both

Comment: @vks Why must everyone insist on being ambiguous? Do you mean he wants both options A and B? Or he wants something "matches *both* expressions"?

Comment: hi thanks for the comments sorry i was out of the forum for a while, yes i need both expressions to be evaluated in a single line both A and B. in between there can be any number of characters

Comment: @JonathonReinhart , thanks for the reply, i said i am trying to search in vs2010 thinking it will be reached to everyone . Point i was trying to make is I was trying to search  through find and replace dialog with an option called search by regular expressions , To find all of the results which has above two keywords .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^global\.ready_.*_get.*$
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: Hello ,Thanks for the quick reply but it is not working. I am new to this expressions so if at all you have considered double quotes those are just for highlighting the text . i wanted to get a line which contains "global.ready_one" and in between any characters and then line should also contain get

Comment: @ansar can you give some sample as this regex does exaclty what you want

Comment: sorry i have made another mistake here , problem here is some of them are assigned to another variable  int SignalVariable = global.ready_one_Manual_getSignal will it work in those cases ?

Comment: @ansar in those cases remove the `^` use `global\.ready_.*_get.*$`